# RHEL 7.2 and SoapUI 5.2.1

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Has anyone successfully installed and run SoapUI 5.2.1 64 bit on a RHEL 7.2 VM? If so what's the magic recipe?

I tried both the "Linux installer (64-bit)" and "Linux tarball (Java not included)" variants without success.

The first symptom when I run the script being the following warning:

```
WARN com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI - Could not find jfxrt.jar.
```

The script also results in a series of the following errors:

```
An error occurred com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
```

There are number of SoapUI community forum articles that are similar but not identical https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/SoapUI-not-working-without-X-since-5-1-0/td-p/42817.

Answer (score 0):

---

Oracle java 8 example : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-sun-1.8.0.92/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`

Oracle java 7 example : `...../java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar`

---

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer buried deep in the SmartBear Community forum.

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/soapui-5-2-freeze-on-startup-on-fedora-23/td-p/111253

Its the one about the hidden screen. It did't quite work exactly as outlined. But I typed into the keyboard, jiggled the screen about and hit the Tab key. Not sure what combination made the invisible screen visible but when it did I then hit skip and everything then became usable.

You get the same screen in a Windows environment but it's displayed not invisible.